# Different users displays in my terminal on university network mac

Tags: mac, security

[image: Screenshot]

Maylinniniphone shows up in my terminal when i'm at the university.. It can be other pc's too.. Why? and is there a security hole?

Comment: easy way to tell; run `nslookup Maylinniniphone`, note its IP address, and check `ifconfig` to determine whether it has the same address as the nslookup result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's due to a badly configured DNS and DHCP server.

Basically at some point shortly before you connected 'Maylinniniphone' was using the same IP you've now been given, and it's not yet updated the DNS record for that IP to return your own hostname instead.

Comment: Ok. So should I not be worried? :)

Comment: in this case, no, because the prompt header token is just your machine name, based on DNS lookup. if you saw other people in `w` or `who` or `ps` that would be alarming, but its just your prompt. here is some info on how to configure your prompt header; perhaps you will find an option that doesn't rely on external host name resolution via DNS. http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/